# Get entity by list of id and check if they exist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Imagine I have classes like:

```
// DTO
public class RequestrDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> CityIds { get; set; }
}

// ENTITY
// PLACE
public class Place
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

// CITY
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? PlaceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public Place Place { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to check if cities exist in the database and add to the newly created entity class which will be added to the DB.

So, I can do like:

```
var placeEntity = new Place() 
{
    Name = RequestrDto.Name;
}
var cities = _context.Cities.Where(x => request.CityIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
placeEntity.Cities.AddRange(cities);
```

How can I get Cities and check if they are in the DB? I know I can iterate over it by foreach but I'm looking for a fancy way.

Comment: So you want a list of ids not found?

Comment: Excactly, I'd like to have list of ids not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8)

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

```
var cities = _context.Cities.Where(x => request.CityIds.Contains(x.Id))
                            .ToList();

var ids = cities.Select(x => x.Id); 
var missing = request.CityIds.Except(ids);

// or

var missing = request.CityIds.Except(cities.Select(x => x.Id));
```